# Android: what is the best way to send presence?

Tags: android, design-patterns, scheduled-tasks, android-handler

I want to send that the user is currently using the app to my server in regular interval.

User is active,

- When he is on any activity of my app and the user should see it in screen.

User is Inactive,

- If the user is not in any of my app's activity
- If the user has minimized the app
- If the user is in my app's activity only, but screen is locked

For this, I have implemented Android's [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) and trying to send user is **active** in `onActivityResumed()` and **inactive** in `onActivityPaused()`

It works as expected, but there are many activities in my app, so transition between Activities also send this presence status, which is very bad for end user.

How can I control this ? How can I send only at regular intervals instead of flooding the presence ?

Generally what is the best way to do something at regular intervals in Android ? which means, the task should be done **only on particular intervals** even it ***has called any number of times***.

**UPDATE**

**How it works now and how do I need:**

Making quick transitions from Launcher -> ActivityA -> ActivityB -> ActivityC

**Current Behaviour:**

```
   A's onResume() triggers userActive()
   A's onPause() triggers userInactive()
   B's onResume() triggers userActive()
   B's onPause() triggers userInactive()
   C's onResume() triggers userActive()
```

**Required Behaviour:**

Since the user is actively in app after all these transitions happen, it should send userActive() only once. It can either send at first transition, (Launcher to ActivityA) or at last transition(ActivityB => ActivityC).

In simple words, the userActive() should not called if it is called within last X seconds.

Comment: use base activity with all other activities which not update on activity change and use all activity life-cycle method on that base activity.

Answer (score 1):

Implement your LifecycleCallback as a singleton or let your Application class implement it. Let it have a counting variable.

```
public void onActivityResumed(){
  if(activeCount == 0){
    // an Activity is active ... do something

  }
  ++activeCount;
}

public void onActivityPaused(){
  --activeCount;
  if(activeCount == 0){
    // all Activities paused
  }
}
```

You may want to synchronize your counting variable or use an atomic integer.

To send info on a regular interval, just let a background service check the value of `activeCount` periodically.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I have just done this before seeing your answer. Seems like we got same wavelength :P

Answer (score 0):

As per Android's documentation, the best way would be to implement dedicated background service which would be establishing connections on a periodic basis and send all new events in one pack.

Most of similar services are designed the same way. Backgound Service has this nice feature that it's one of the first to be killed when system is running out of memory, thus your other activities will remain intact and be running smoothly. Once resources are available again, you could configure it to pick up from where it left and send the report to your servers.

My personal rule of a thumb: if something is not directly related to handling user controls, make it as a service

--- Edit 1: 
[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html)